# How to render a mat-radio-button option on a condition in angular? I don't want to repeat div's

Tags: angular

I want to render "serialNumber" mat-radio-button if myService.specialDealer is true and "vin" mat-radio-button if myService.specialDealer is false.

I have used the following code to achieve it but I read somewhere that *ngIf can't be directly applied to mat-radio-button option. I don't want to repeat div's. Is there any better approch to acheive this?

```html
<mat-radio-group (change)="onChange()" [(ngModel)]="myModel.key">
<mat-radio-button value="contractNumber">{{'certificate'}}</mat-radio-button>
<mat-radio-button value="vin" *ngIf="!myService.specialDealer">{{ 'vin'}}</mat-radio-button>
<mat-radio-button value="serialNumber" *ngIf="myService.specialDealer">{{ 'serialnumber'}}</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on an array of radio buttons and evaluate the visible condition without if statements.

Example:

```js
export class RadioExample {
  radioButtons = [
    { label: 'certificate', 
      value: 'contractNumber',
      visible: () => true  // <-- call your service here to evalute this condition
    },
    { label: 'vin', 
      value: 'vin',
      visible: () => false  // <-- call your service here to evalute this condition
    }
  ];

  // I am filtering my visible buttons here to demostrate how you can
  // avoid if statement
  // however you might use a pipe on the template to filter
  // or another approach to filter
  radioButtonsFiltered = this.radioButtons.filter((radiobutton) => radiobutton.visible());
}
```

```html
<mat-radio-group>
  <mat-radio-button
    *ngFor="let radio of radioButtonsFiltered"
    [value]="radio.value"
  >
    {{ radio.label | translate }}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your controls inside a `<div>` and apply *ngIf to those:

```
 <div *ngIf="!claimService.getIsSpecialtyEquipmentDealer">
     <mat-radio-button value="vin" >{{ 'vin' | translate }}</mat-radio-button>
 </div>
 <div *ngIf="claimService.getIsSpecialtyEquipmentDealer">
    <mat-radio-button value="serialNumber" >{{ 'serialnumber' | translate }}</mat-radio-button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi Trismuto, Thanks for the solution but I wanted to avoid using so many divs.